# How to remove the separaor in dock macos Catalina?

Tags: macos, mac, macos-mojave, dock, macos-catalina

[dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9leCp.png)

I used the script below and successful removed the finder icon and trash icon in dock, but there has a separator in the right, is there any way to remove this separator in mac? im using catalina

https://github.com/jesscXC/hide-finder-trash-dock-icons

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get close to that using **cDock**. You can use it's **Color separator layer** option with any color and then set it's opacity to **0%**.

I said it's close to what you want 'cause the separator will still be there, making the right border of the dock larger than the left border, but it will no longer be visible.

PS. cDock is a paid app, but they offer a trial period.